# Codeigniter fluctuations in performance

Tags: php, codeigniter, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have centos 7 virtual machine which I use to host all my projects and databases and everything is working fine, then couple of days ago I noticed that in one of my applications (this one is using CodeIgniter for API - and this is the only one that is using CodeIgniter) I have variations in response times on the same actions, sometimes it takes less than 50ms, and sometimes it takes more than 20 seconds.

With the same database configuration and with the same data in that database, nothing changed at all.

Does CodeIgniter keep some cache somewhere or something like that which can impact performance sometimes?

**EDIT**

One more thing, after some more thinking and testing. Is it possible that my mobile app (the one that is using that api) could be sometimes throttling the requests? I have no idea why it would do that, but still.
It's a hybrid app made using cordova and custom javascript and html (on my part of the javascript, there is nothing that could do that, so the only other problem could be cordova and it's plugins)

Cordova version 7.0.1

**Cordova plugins used:**

com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"

com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"

cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"

cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"

cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack 0.0.4 "CocoaLumberjack"

cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"

cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"

cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.5 "Device Motion"

cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"

cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"

cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.19 "File Opener2"

cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"

cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"

cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"

cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"

cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"

ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 "PushPlugin"

Anyone has any idea where to look and how to test?

Comment: debug your application and check where spikes go

Comment: Codeigniter by default does not cache anything but you can cache web pages, I also think the available resources also impact on performnce

Comment: Im using it as an api, so it returns no html or other resources, the same requests fluctuate a lot, the ones that accept the same data and return the same data.

Comment: A wild guess: Your API uses sessions for authentication, and the "flucations" happen when the same client makes multiple requests?